# Writing/reading a matrix in and from a file in internal storage

Tags: java, android, matrix

In my app I've created a matrix, three buttons (a load, save and check button), and some TextView and EditText fields. The load button is supposed to load a matrix from an existing text file in internal storage while the save button should save the matrix to the same file. The check button should search if a combination from the EditText fields exists and if it does it should show the result of the combination, if not it should ask you to enter the results which gets saved in the matrix.

The check button works, however I can't get the load and save buttons to work correctly. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
float[][] kvote = new float[200][8];
int counter=0;
String str;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//Button, TextView and EditView initialization

LOAD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("Text.txt");
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
                String line=null;
                String[] numbers=null;
                float x;
                int i=0;
                while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                    numbers=line.split("\\d\\s+");

                    x=Float.valueOf(numbers[0].trim());
                    kvote[counter][i]=x;
                    counter++;
                    i++;
                    if(i==8)
                        i=0;
                }
                br.close();
                fin.close();
                str="File loaded.";
                Disp.setText(str);
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });


SAVE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            try {
                FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("Text.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
                BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fOut));
                for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
                    for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
                    {
                        bwr.write(Float.toString(kvote[i][j]));
                        bwr.write("\n");
                    }
                bwr.close();
                fOut.close();
                str="File saved";
                Disp.setText(str);
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
Check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...}
}
```

Comment: “*I can't get the load and save buttons to work correctly*” In what way do they work now (as opposed to correctly)? Also in case of any error message and/or stacktrace, please quote it exactly in the question.

Comment: “Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).” (quoted from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Apparently I wasn't loading the floats into the matrix properly. I only needed to put the counter++ in the if(i==8) statement, rookie mistake. How would I go about writing and reading from a specific file though since I cannot see this one?